# Grabbing string between two other strings using Google Apps Scripts and Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I'm using Google Apps scripts to parse out a mailbox.
I'm not having any trouble identifying the messages I want to parse, the problem comes in when I want to grab a specific chunk of text from the plainBody of the messages.

an excerpt of the Plain Body:

```
Technical details of permanent failure: 
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain domain.com by aspmx.l.google.com. [173.194.77.26].

The error that the other server returned was:
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 y3si2744337oex.60 - gsmtp


----- Original message -----

X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=1e100.net; s=20130820;
```

I'm attempting to grab all the lines that start with 550 (at least, they start with 550 in this example, could be any number of codes starting those lines)

The code I'm using to attempt to grab it is

```
var bodyRegex = new RegExp("The error that the other server returned was:[\s\S]*----- Original message -----");
Logger.log(bodyRegEx.exec(plainBody));
```

It's just returning *null*

Using RegExLib I'm able to use this RegEx successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try escaping your slashes since you're compiling a RegExp object:

```
var bodyRegex = new RegExp("The error that the other server returned was:[\\s\\S]*----- Original message -----");
```

or just use the literal:

```
var bodyRegex = /The error that the other server returned was:[\s\S]*----- Original message -----/;
```